# SQLAlchemy I/O where parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm currently working on a project with a database I use through SQLAlchemy I/O and I stumble on a problem I can't solve. In the following DbSession is an asynchronous session and select is the select function of the library.

I have a class Player with 3 attributes id: BigInteger (Primary Key), name: String, other_id(nullable, if not null can serve as a primary key): BigInteger.

```
class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = "players"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    other_id = Column(BigInteger, nullable=True)
```

I implemented 2 methods get and get_by_id:
get is working well and select a Player in the table through its id:

```
    @classmethod
    async def get(cls, id):
        query = select(cls).where(cls.id == id)
        results = await DbSession.execute(query)
        result = results.scalars().all()[0]
        return result
```

My problem comes with get_by_id which is supposed to find a player through its other_id.

I tried:

```
    @classmethod
    async def get_dc_id(cls, id):
        query = select(cls).filter(cls.other_id == id)
        results = await DbSession.execute(query)
        result = results.scalars().all()[0]
        return result
```

As well as:

```
    @classmethod
    async def get_dc_id(cls, id):
        query = select(cls).where(cls.other_id == id)
        results = await DbSession.execute(query)
        result = results.scalars().all()[0]
        return result
```

But both send back an error:

```
ProgrammingError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.ProgrammingError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.UndefinedFunctionError'>: operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
[SQL: SELECT players.id, players.name, players.other_id 
FROM players 
WHERE players.other_id = %s]
[parameters: (331534096054616068,)]
```

If I understand this right, the parameter of the call is actually the id I gave to my function but wrapped in a sort of tuple (that comes from I don't know where). It throws an error as this tuple doesn't match the type BigInteger other_id is supposed to have. I checked multiple times that I'm effectively giving an integer as an argument to get_by_id (here equal to 331534096054616068). I must admit that I don't know why the id ends up wrapped in a tuple, if it's a normal behavior or not as I just started working with sqlalchemy.

Any hint or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the tuple is just the sequence of params, so for example if there was another condition in the `WHERE` clause that used a constant, `age = 400`, then output would be `parameters: (331534096054616068, 400)`.  I don't think its the problem but my exception is slightly different than yours and displays the params as a dictionary but I think maybe our lib versions differ.

Comment: Not a solution for your error, but note that [Session.get](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.get) will fetch by primary key.

Comment: Similar discussion on GitHub https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/7814

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your actual schema differs and `other_id` is a STRING column.

Can you inspect the postgresql db directly with psql and check if `\d players` is correct?

I get the same error if I change your column definition to `other_id = Column(String, nullable=True)` and create the db schema but it works if I recreate the schema with `other_id = Column(BigInteger, nullable=True)`.

Comment: I'm using postgresql 11.14 and SQLAlchemy 1.4.31.

Comment: operator does not exist: character varying = bigint, in the error shows that he  is actually looking for a bigint no?

Comment: Plus I actually added some values (integers) in the column and I have no error whatsoever

Comment: The parameter is bigint but the column appears to be character varying.  That's why I thought they should double check the actual table schema in the database in case the database column type didn't get created or migrated correctly.